# Wordpress reset password returns invalid key

Tags: password

I'm currently trying to build a custom reset password form, which seems to work fine up until it needs to validate the key for the user:

```
//Redirect away from default wordpress to reset password
function redirect_to_reset_password() {
    if ( 'GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
        // Verify key / login combo
        $user = check_password_reset_key( $_REQUEST['key'], $_REQUEST['login'] );
        if ( ! $user || is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
            if ( $user && $user->get_error_code() === 'expired_key' ) {
                wp_redirect( home_url( '/login?login=expiredkey/' ) );
            } else {
                wp_redirect( home_url( '/login?login=invalidkey/' ) );
            }
            exit;
        }

        $redirect_url = home_url( '/reset-password/' );
        $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'login', esc_attr( $_REQUEST['login'] ), $redirect_url );
        $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'key', esc_attr( $_REQUEST['key'] ), $redirect_url );

        wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('login_form_rp', 'redirect_to_reset_password');
add_action('login_form_resetpass', 'redirect_to_reset_password');

//Make new password
function do_password_reset() {
    if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
        $rp_key = $_REQUEST['rp_key'];
        $rp_login = $_REQUEST['rp_login'];
        $user = check_password_reset_key( $rp_key, $rp_login );

        if ( ! $user || is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
            if ( $user && $user->get_error_code() === 'expired_key' ) {
                wp_redirect( home_url( '/login?login=expiredkey/' ) );
            } else {
                wp_redirect( home_url( '/login?login=invalidkey/' ) );
            }
            exit;
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) {
            if ( $_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2'] ) {
                // Passwords don't match
                $redirect_url = home_url( '/reset-password/' );

                $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'key', $rp_key, $redirect_url );
                $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'login', $rp_login, $redirect_url );
                $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'error', 'password_reset_mismatch', $redirect_url );

                wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
                exit;
            }

            if ( empty( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) {
                // Password is empty
                $redirect_url = home_url( '/reset-password/' );

                $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'key', $rp_key, $redirect_url );
                $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'login', $rp_login, $redirect_url );
                $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'error', 'password_reset_empty', $redirect_url );

                wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
                exit;
            }

            // Parameter checks OK, reset password
            reset_password( $user, $_POST['pass1'] );
            wp_redirect( home_url( '/login?password=changed/' ) );
        } else {
            echo "Invalid request.";
        }

        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'login_form_rp', 'do_password_reset' );
add_action( 'login_form_resetpass', 'do_password_reset' );
```

I've been snooping around trying to figure out what the cause of the issue can be, and I've found that the key under user_activation_key is not the same as the one I get in my URL when trying to reset my password. E.g:

DB: `1553346836:$P$BYEbftAGRfnhlBTeuNL4ylhsxRyhS3/`

URL: `key=dx1GjoJnaD6Dytc5zpNq`

I assume this is just wordpress' way of encrypting the key so it shouldn't cause this issue, but it is the only inconsistency I've been able to find.

EDIT: If I try and check what value $user is set to, I get an undefined index error regarding `$_REQUEST['rp_key']` and `$_REQUEST['rp_login']`. I then tried to var_dump $_REQUEST which gave me the following: `array(2) { ["login"]=> string(20) "my@mail.com" ["key"]=> string(20) "nWrRCsRD4OvaROeMFErV" }`. Following this I changed $_REQUEST['rp_key'] to $_REQUEST['key'] and the same for login, but I still get the same undefined index error. But the value is in the $_REQUEST array, why can't it find it?

Could the fact that I'm using `check_password_reset_key` twice have an effect on the key being set to invalid?

EDIT2: 
Running the code through a environment running https resulted in a "Bad Request" return.

Comment: So you're saying that check_password_reset_key always gives you invalid_key ? Yes, the DB value is the timestamp you requested the reset (which is four days old now: resets are only valid for 24 hours by default) and a phpass hash of the key.

Comment: That hashed key is correct. From wp-includes, `php -a` `require_once("class-phpass.php");` `echo ((new PasswordHash(8,true))->CheckPassword('dx1GjoJnaD6Dytc5zpNq', '$P$BYEbftAGRfnhlBTeuNL4ylhsxRyhS3/')) ? "true" : "false";` gives me "true".

Comment: Have you checked, isn't there a way to re-render or re-use WordPress’ built-in password reset form/code?

Comment: @Rup so am I correct in assuming the error is either how I use check_password_reset_key or how I request the key and login?

Comment: I don't know, sorry: at first glance it looks correct to me. If those are the exact values you're feeding into check_password_reset_key then it ought to work. Assuming you're not hitting the reset-key-expired error that is, but that returns 'expired_key'.

Comment: @Rup it seems to me the $_REQUEST['rp_key'] doesn't return anything, I'll look further

Comment: After debugging I can confirm that my $_REQUEST['rp_key'] and $_REQUEST['rp_login'] are returning undefined index. I however still fail to see why.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with this, I assume you're working from this guide - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-wordpress-user-flow-part-3-password-reset--cms-23811

Have a look at the actual reset password form where it shows pass1 and pass2. The hidden fields values are automatically set to `$attribute['key']` and `$attribute['login']`.

Changing this to `$_REQUEST['key']` and `$_REQUEST['login']` should solve the issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is the fact that you're using `$_REQUEST` instead of explicitly looking for `GET` or `POST` variables.

I think you already solved the first issue which is that the first step of the process (where you request a reset) passes `key` and `login` via `$_GET` variables. This allows `redirect_to_reset_password()` to redirect appropriately.

The next part is a bit different. The reset password form passes the following:

```
Array (
    [action] => resetpass
    [pass1] => [text]
    [pass1-text] => [text]
    [pass2] => [text]
    [rp_key] => [text]
    [wp-submit] => Reset Password
)
```

Unless you're doing something to change these fields on a form from your `/reset-password/` page, `rp_login` will never be set. [`wp-login.php` shows a different process](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-login.php#L654) to retrieving the necessary pieces to run `check_password_reset_key()`

```
if ( isset( $_COOKIE[ $rp_cookie ] ) && 0 < strpos( $_COOKIE[ $rp_cookie ], ':' ) ) {
        list( $rp_login, $rp_key ) = explode( ':', wp_unslash( $_COOKIE[ $rp_cookie ] ), 2 );
        $user                      = check_password_reset_key( $rp_key, $rp_login );
        if ( isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) && ! hash_equals( $rp_key, $_POST['rp_key'] ) ) {
            $user = false;
        }
}
```

You can see it's checking the `rp_cookie` that was set earlier in the process. From here it's retrieving the login and key then checking the cookie's key against the key passed via a `POST` variable.

You will need to do something similar to make this work.